# Prime in text mode

Tags: symbols

How do I produce the prime symbol in text mode? In math mode the prime symbol is produced by `'` but in text mode it produces something else.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you really want the math prime symbol you may simply use `$'$` or `$\prime$`, or if you want to use it in text and math mode `\ensuremath{'}` or `\ensuremath{\prime}`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\everymodeprime}{\ensuremath{\prime}}
\begin{document}
Prime in text mode: \everymodeprime

Prime in math mode: $\everymodeprime$
\end{document}
```

I've used `\prime` instead of `'` to avoid typo mistakes.

`\ensuremath` does only switch to math mode, if math mode it not already active. So it is often useful to define commands, that uses math mode commands and should work in text and math mode.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that $'$ and $\prime$ are interchangeable, but they're not:  $'$ is a superscript-sized and -positioned $\prime$.

Answer (score 20):

The `flexisym` package offers `\textprime` which can be directly used in math or in text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}

a\textprime

$a\textprime$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there's a `\prime` character in text mode.  If you want an upright single quote, you can use `\textquotesingle` defined in the `textcomp` package; alternatively if you actually want a prime, then you can just use `$'$` in text mode.

Comment: I want an actual prime but I don't want to go via inline math mode.

Comment: N.N.: Why not, if this is the character you want, but `\textquotesingle`, `\textquoteleft`, and `\textquoteright` aren't?

Comment: @Schweinebacke I want to use prime in list labels and then refer to the list items from math mode but that seems to force me to nest math modes which leads to errors, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36658/how-to-refer-to-labels-in-math-mode-in-math-mode.

Comment: The `flexisym` package defines \textprime: `\DeclareRobustCommand\textprime{\leavevmode
 \raise.8ex\hbox{\text@char\scriptfont\prime}%
 }`

Comment: N.N.: `\ensuremath{'}` may be used to nest math, because it switchs to math only if your are not in math mode already.

Comment: @Schweinebacke You should make that an answer stating that there's no need to try to write prime in text mode since `\ensuremath` let's you nest math.

Comment: @N.N.: Ok, I was short in time, so I've hoped, that a comment would be enough.

Answer (score 8):

Using `flexisym` requires subduing to its weird decision about several symbols.

It's much simpler to use

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommand{\textprime}{\encodingdefault}{%
  \mbox{$\m@th'\kern-\scriptspace$}% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a\textprime{} b

$a\textprime$

\end{document}
```

With `\DeclareTextCommand` we disallow using the symbol in math mode (a warning will be produced); with `\mbox` we avoid an error, if `\textprime` is issued in math mode nonetheless; with `\m@th` we nullify a possible nonzero value of `\mathsurround`; with `\kern-\scriptspace` we remove the kerning that's added after subscripted or superscripted math atoms.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Unicode, prime is ′ (U+2032).  You can use it with `fontspec` if your text font supports it.  The result probably won’t match prime in math mode.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand\textprime{\char"2032}

\begin{document}

30\textprime

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine font sample]