# How to refer to labels in math mode from math mode

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, enumerate

If you refer to item labels that are written in math mode from some other math mode occurrence, then you get errors. I guess it's because it leads to nested math modes. Is there any way to avoid these errors?

Here's an example where referring to the first label in math mode gives one error and referring to the second label gives another:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}% For the label with \( \) to work

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=$e'_{\arabic*}$]
\item Bla bla bla\label{e1}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\(e'_{\arabic*}\)]
\item Bla bla bla\label{vare1}
\end{enumerate}

\(h \mid \ref{e1}\)

\(h \mid \ref{vare1}\)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `ensuremath` to help you out here. The following compiles for me. I replaced the dollar signs with the `ensuremath` environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\ensuremath{e'_{\arabic*}}]
\item Bla bla bla\label{e1}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{e1}
\(h \mid \ref{e1}\)
```

Alternatively you can use `mbox`

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=$e'_{\arabic*}$]
\item Bla bla bla\label{e1}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{e1}
\(h \mid \mbox{\ref{e1}}\)
```

Comment: I'm curious why this works. If you know could you please include some explanation in your answer?

Comment: I assume it's because the `ensuremath` is only expanded when the label is referenced. That is a guess however, and when I tried this out I expected it to fail.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows and cares to elaborate. What did you mean by "I guess it'd be back to front..." in your comment to my question?

Comment: I expected `ensuremath` to be doing the same as `$...$`, so I was thinking about something to do the opposite. i.e. an `ensurenotmath` to put around the `ref`. Outside an equation the ref would be the usual `\ref{e1}`, and inside an equation it'd be `$...\ensurenotmath{\ref{e1}}$`.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer either of your solutions? The one with `\ensuremath` seems better because it don't require to `\mbox` every occurence of `\ref`.

Comment: It depends. If you have a lot of labels set already then you'll only be hitting this problem when you reach the odd case of a `ref` in math mode. In that case fixing it per math mode will be easier with an `mbox`.

Comment: Plus it's also clearer to me why `mbox` works. I feel more comfortable when I know *why* something is working.