# Possible bug in flexsym

Tags: symbols, debugging

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36753/14757) we find a solution to use prime in text mode, via `\textprime` from `flexisym` package.

The problem is that the package has a problem with `amsmath`, since it makes  `\dots` not be aligned according to surrounding symbols. Also, some space problem around `=` sign.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flexisym} % should be after amsmath

\begin{document}

a\textprime $a\textprime$

$a\otimes\dots\otimes b $ and $|X|=n$.
\end{document}
```

Just to compare, the right output.

[image]

Comment: Don't use `flexisym`,

Comment: @egreg, what is alternative to prime in text mode?

Comment: I added a different solution; `flexisym` has many more “features” than you'd like to plague your document with.

Comment: @egreg, I'll take a look.