# Standard with respect to super+subscript

Tags: vertical-alignment, superscripts

I had an annoying problem with primes - since two automatically turn into quotation marks, and I had some double and triple primed variables, I introduced the textprime solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36655/prime-in-text-mode/36697) by egreg - all others in that link clashed with my many packages, or gave wrong spacing when coming in pairs. (Otherwise I would have been forced to go through all 150 pages of my document, which also contains quote primes and apostroph primes, sometimes inside, sometimes outside math.)
I paid a price, though: `$a^b_c$` still aligns the super- and subscript just like `$a'_c$`, but `$a\textprime_c$` doesn't. I declared that as a feature and not a bug, since I find it looks OK, but: Is there a standard how super+subscripts *should* look (i.e., aligning them, otherwise it wouldn't be the default)? If "very yes" (i.e. a TEXpert would frown at my text), could egreg's solution be modified to solve this issue too?

Comment: you have shown no code but your first sentence sounds wrong, ' ' only turns into " in text, but primed variables should be marked up as math.

Comment: `\textprime` as defined at that link is just for text and just for a single prime it doesn't have the code to turn `x''` into `x^{\prime\prime}` that `'` has.